# Combine history api and hashes in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue.js and vue-router. I am trying  to achieve the following:

I have a top navigation bar with navigation links. Some of them are links to other client-side routes so they are basic vue-router `router-link` component except one which needs to point to a component with the same `id` attribute value on the same page.

First, I have coded it as an HTML Anchor Element, `a`, with an `href` attribute value equals to the `id` attribute value of the target component.
Alternatively, I have tried to use a `router-link` with `to` attribute has the `/`, home path concatenated with href (id) value, so, `/#target_id`.

First way resulted unsuccessful on the routes other than the target element resides in, a bit obvious.
Second way also unsuccessful. It does not work even on the route that contains the target element, though updates the address bar properly. It also cannot reach to the target element from the other routes that do not contain the target element by ending only on the route with target element at the top of the page.

How to tell vue-router to not only reach the route and render the corresponding component but also follow the hash parts and reaching to the correct region on the page?

Probably I can render navigation links conditionally as `anchors` or `router-link` with respect to the current route, and then can invoke a `window.location` related change on a vue component lifecycle method on the target containing component. Or just use some vue component level or applicaiton level routing hooks.

Comment: you can use scrollBehavior of vue-router
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (to.hash) {
    return {
      selector: to.hash
    }
  }
}

see: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#scrollbehavior